# Need help in configuring share folder

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am setting up a file server/backup server named "NAS" on an old machine running Bodhi linux and I have to share some folders on the server so they are accessible from the network.

On the network, besides "NAS", I have one workstation running Ubuntu 14.04, another workstation running Windows 7, and an Android TVBox.

The shared folders on "NAS" should be accessible from the two workstations.
Ideally the shared folders should also be accessed by the Android TV Box, but this is not so important. I guess if I manage to get access to the shared folder(s) on NAS from the ubuntu WORKSTATION, I will also get access to it from the TV BOX, as it easily connects to the shared folders on the Ubuntu workstation.

Bodhi is a very lightweight distribution based on Ubuntu Xenial, but it is VERY minimal. So minimal that even the basic networking packages (such as Samba) were missing.
I installed the necessary packages though, and I also installed Nautilus, in the hope I could manage to share a network folder through the file manager (same as I do in Ubuntu 14.04), but I can't get the shared folder to work.

If I search the network from the Ubuntu 14.04 workstation, NAS is displayed among the resources, but when I try to connect I get a refused connection error message .

I followed about 10 different tutorials (so this question will probably be marked as duplicate) and been working two days on how to configure the Samba Server on NAS but nothing seems to work for me, and I can't get access to the shared folder.

I guess I need some help to setup it up correctly.

Here the result of smbclient run from the Ubuntu Workstation:

```
gc@PC:~$ /usr/bin/smbclient -L 192.168.0.102
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter gc's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
NAS_share       Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (NAS server (Samba, Ubuntu))
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
NAS                  NAS server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            PC
```

EDIT

I can see the shared folder on NAS (NAS_share) if I use the "connect to server" interface on the Ubuntu file manager (smb://192.168.0.102), but I can't access the folder since the password I set up in samba is not recognized....
I'm sure about the username and password as I use the same on all machines, and its the same I use to log into all the systems.

EDIT

testparm -s

```
cg@NAS:~$ testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[NAS_share]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
    [global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    security = USER
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew
    \s*\spassword:                    
    * %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


    [printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    printable = Yes
    browseable = No


    [print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


    [NAS_share]
    comment = NAS_share
    path = /home/cgiammiro/NAS_share
    valid users = @users
    force group = users
    group = users
    read only = No
    create mask = 0660
    directory mask = 0771
    directory mode = 0771
```

net usershare info --long

```
[NAS_share]
path=/home/cg/NAS_share
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

Comment: "Bodhi is a very lightweight distribution based on Ubuntu Xenial" but not an official Ubuntu and therefore off topic. Same for Android TV Box and Windows. http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is our sister site for Linux related questios; you should ask it there BUT I would suggest to include the config you make on Bodhi for samba. Your problem is likely with those settings Otherwise it might be a firewall issue.

Comment: This is the result /usr/bin/smbclient 

`code`

Comment: NAS_share is the test folder I'm trying to share

WORKGROUP     PC  is the Ubuntu Workstation I am trying to connect from

Comment: The "config you make on Bodhi for samba" that Rinzwind referred to is the output of these two commands: "testparm -s" and "net usershare info --long"

Comment: Edited my question with output of "testparm -s" and "net usershare info --long"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably you didn't post all of the testparm output - specifically the [global] section which would have told us how the samba server itself was configured. Based on the info you provided here are my observations:

[1] You created two different shares using two different methods of the same folder with the same name and they are configured differently. One is the standard samba share which allows only members of the users group access to the share. The other is a samba usershare which allows everyone access.

Choose one or the other but not both since it's just a guess as to which one samba will obey. I would recommend getting rid of the usershare so go back into Nautilus and remove the sharing of /home/cg/NAS_share.

[2] The share in smb.conf requires credentials to access and if you are using the same username ( I'm guessing it's cg ) on all your machines you need to add that username to the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a cg
```

[3] Since this is a home network you made your share definition way to complicated. It looks like it would work but I would have done it this way:

```
[NAS_share]
    comment = NAS_share
    path = /home/cg/NAS_share
    valid users = cg
    read only = No
```

**EDIT**: **If you want a share that requires no login credentials I would make the share look like this:**

```
[NAS_share]
    comment = NAS_share
    path = /home/cg/NAS_share
    guest ok = Yes
    force user = cg 
    read only = No
```

Since NAS_share is likely owned by the user cg you shouldn't have any Linux permissions issues so you wouldn't have to make any changes to the Linux permissions on the NAS_share folder itself.

**EDIT: Your addition of the [global] section looks like the standard way Ubuntu does this sort of thing with the exception of this line:**

> username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

If the file is empty don't worry about it. If it has something in it it may be a problem if it's pointing to a user that doesn't exist or one that has no samba password.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I updated the question with the whole testparm output. It is possible that I created two shares out of the same folder, I've been messing with this and tried different tutorials. Perhaps it could be useful if I wipe everything out (including Samba) and reinstall and restart from scratch ?
I don't need login credentials at all, matter of fact a simple access without credential is what I am looking for.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your new information.

Comment: 1. I went back to Nautilus and removed the share as per your suggestion

Comment: 2. I changed NAS_share reflecting your suggested config
3. /etc/samba/smbuser doesn't even exist. However I am sure that at some point I was asked for the samba password (and the unix password) for user cg.

I still can't access NAS_share. When I try to access the share from "search network" in filemanager I still get the same message connection refused. 
When I try to access the share from connect to server I get the message invalid argument

Comment: I restarted NAS and now when I "connect to server" instead of the error message I get a blank window. Like there's no shares on "NAS". If I browse the network I get the usual message connection refused

Comment: I commented out "username map = /etc/samba/smbusers" but still no connection. NAS_share has reappeared though if I "connect to server"

Comment: Ok, so I added "public = yes" to Nas_share in smb.conf and finally I can access the share from connect to server. For some unknown reason I still keep getting the error message when I try to access the share from "search network" but no big deal. Thank you Morbius1 !